# Return a struct from C to Python using Cython

Tags: python, c, struct, cython

I am trying to pass a struct back into my Python from a c file. Let's say I have a file pointc.c like this:

```
typedef struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
} Point;

struct Point make_and_send_point(int x, int y);

struct Point make_and_send_point(int x, int y) {
    struct Point p = {x, y};
    return p;
}
```

Then I set-up a point.pyx file like this:

```
"# distutils: language = c"
# distutils: sources = pointc.c

cdef struct Point:
    int x
    int y

cdef extern from "pointc.c":
    Point make_and_send_point(int x, int y)

def make_point(int x, int y):
    return make_and_send_point(x, y) // This won't work, but compiles without the 'return' in-front of the function call
```

How do I get the returned struct into my Python? Is this kind of thing only possible by creating a struct in the Cython and sending by reference to a void c function?

As a reference, my setup.py is:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(
      "point.pyx",
      language="c"
     )
)
```

Comment: This is not going to be a helpful comment, but I never really understood why does cython exist. Writing python modules in c is rather easy and better than using cython.

Comment: Fair enough, are there any resources you suggest that I look at for writing python modules directly? I am new to interfacing c with python. It was my understanding that Cython had some powerful tools, albeit somewhat of a cost to get into. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Yes, the python official documentation. Just google [writing python modules in c](https://www.google.co.ve/search?client=firefox-b-ab&dcr=0&ei=TWuZWuLEJM2UzwKL8YmoCw&q=writing+python+modules+in+c&oq=writing+python+modules+in+c&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3077.3634.0.3735.5.4.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..5.0.0....0.U-NLoWK3lOw) and choose the version that you will be targeting. That's actually a pain in the **** about python, the 2 and 3 version incompatibility sucks.

Comment: Contrasting opinion - if you're going to be interacting much with python objects, I think cython is significantly more convenient - no new APIs to learn and reference counting book-keeping, which can be subtle to get right, is taken care of.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most typically you would write some kind of wrapper class that holds the c-level struct, for example:

```
# point.pyx
cdef extern from "pointc.c":
    ctypedef struct Point:
        int x
        int y
    Point make_and_send_point(int x, int y)

cdef class PyPoint:
    cdef Point p

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.p = make_and_send_point(x, y)

    @property
    def x(self):
       return self.p.x

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.p.y
```

In usage

```
>>> import point
>>> p = point.PyPoint(10, 10)
>>> p.x
10
```

Comment: Thanks, I went about it slightly different, kind of like @DavidW points out by just getting the returned dictionary. But I like this answer, it shows how I could actually implement classes between c and python a little clearer than I was able to find online. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Cython's default behaviour given a struct is to convert it to a Python dictionary, which may be good enough for you. (This only works for structs made up of simple types though).

There's a couple of reasons why this isn't working. First you should do `cdef extern from` from *headers*, not source files, otherwise you get errors about multiple definitions (I assume this is just a mistake in creating your minimal example). Second you need to put the definition of `Point` within your `cdef extern` block:

```
cdef extern from "pointc.h":
    cdef struct Point:
        int x
        int y
```

If you don't do that then Cython creates a mangled internal name for your struct (`__pyx_t_5point_Point`) which doesn't match the C function signature and thus it fails.

With this corrected, you get the correct default behaviour of converting structs to dicts. (This should work both ways - you can convert dicts back to structs). In the event that this isn't what you want, follow @chrisb's answer

Comment: Thanks, yea this is what I ended up doing initially. I made the Cython struct then passed it by reference to a void make_and_send function in the c.

Comment: By the way, the c file is fairly simple so I put all the function declarations at the top and I don't get any warning by doing cdef extern from "pointc.c". Is there documentation that says I should use headers and why?

Comment: In C terms the `cdef extern from ...` block includes the file. As a rule in C you should only include headers to avoid having multiple copies of the same code. This is something that you should look up from a C point of view, rather than a Cython point of view. Depending on the compiler you may not get an error/warning, so if it works then it's fine, but it might not be best practice.